# Unmarshal output is testfuzzy.FuzzyController@2f678f0e

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

Why is my unmarshal output so strange?

Any ideas?

This is my unmarshal code:

When I run this, I got this error.

**Unmarshal output** is

Comment: Override `toString` in `FuzzyController`. You're getting the `toString` from `Object`.

Comment: Elaborate, please?

Comment: Sure. `System.out.println(fct);` ***is*** `System.out.println(fct.toString());` and you didn't provide a `toString` in `FuzzyController`; so you get the one from `Object`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

```
FuzzyController fct=(FuzzyController) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
System.out.println(fct);
```

You are getting object fct. which is `testfuzzy.FuzzyController@2f678f0e`. It is not error, it's object.

**Use this code:**

```
FuzzyController fct=(FuzzyController) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
System.out.println(fct.toString());
```

This will give you all in a array.

For better understanding, follow the tutorials:

1. http://www.javatpoint.com/jaxb-unmarshalling-example
2. http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/
3. https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html